# Removing newline character in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, newline

I've got a really simple yet infuriating PowerShell question here. I'm trying to remove a newline character from a string. I have the following code:

```
param(
[parameter(mandatory=$false)]$Dmn = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()
)

function getPDC{
    $Domain = $Dmn.Name.Split('.')[0]
    $PDC = (nltest /dcname:$Domain).Replace("PDC for Domain ","").Replace($Domain, "").Replace(" is \\","").Replace("The command completed successfully","").Replace("`n","")
    $PDC + "hodor"
}
```

Which, if it would work how I understand it to, should return

```
PDCVALUEhodor
```

But instead it returns:

```
PDCVALUE

hodor
```

What is the dumb mistake I'm making here?

I tried casting $PDC as a string like so:

```
[String]$PDC = [String](nltest /dcname:$Domain).Replace("PDC for Domain ","").Replace($Domain, "").Replace(" is \\","").Replace("The command completed successfully","").Replace(" ", "")
```

And the line breaks disappeared (weird!), giving me

```
PDCVALUE hodor
```

which is closer to what I want, but I can't seem to remove that space. I tried calling `Replace(" ", "")` and `Trim()` on the string, both of which didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, apparently replacing the line

```
$PDC+"hodor"
```

with

```
($PDC+"hodor").Replace(" ", "")
```

worked. I had to use the Replace function on the entire string ($PDC + "hodor"), not just $PDC for some reason. Also, the Trim function didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `.Replace()` try `.TrimEnd()`

```powershell
$PDC.TrimEnd("`r?`n") + "hodor"
```